# gcloud: docker pull says "authentication required" after successful login

Tags: docker, coreos, gcloud

I have VM with CoreOS in *Compute engine* and image inside *Container Registry*.

I'm following this instruction https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication and run

```
$ docker login -e mymail@gmail.com -u oauth2accesstoken -p "$(gcloud auth print-access-token)" https://gcr.io

Flag --email has been deprecated, will be removed in 1.13.
Login Succeeded


$ docker pull gcr.io/myproject/web:v1.0.0
v1.0.0: Pulling from myproject/web
709515475419: Pulling fs layer 
943e0887e008: Pulling fs layer 
c99fe67ba1a0: Pulling fs layer 
2cfe3fdc59a2: Waiting 
2c5b377ae620: Waiting 
dc0cee14b1bf: Waiting 
error pulling image configuration: unauthorized: authentication required
```

I've [tried to check authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36022892/how-to-know-if-docker-is-already-logged-in-to-a-docker-registry-server)

```
$ docker info
Containers: 10
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 10
Images: 2
Server Version: 1.12.6
Storage Driver: overlay
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: null host bridge overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Security Options: seccomp selinux
Kernel Version: 4.9.9-coreos-r1
Operating System: Container Linux by CoreOS 1298.6.0 (Ladybug)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 3.618 GiB
Name: **********************
ID: **********************
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
```

What's wrong with `docker login`, why it reports about successful login but **gcr.io** doesn't appear in `docker info`?

Answer (score 3):

I found another way: use `gcloud docker -- pull gcr.io/myproject/web:v1.0.0`

Because gcloud running inside container it didn't find docker. To fix that I use following:

`alias gcloud='(docker images google/cloud-sdk || docker pull google/cloud-sdk) > /dev/null;docker run --rm -t -i --net=host -v $HOME/.config:/.config -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker google/cloud-sdk gcloud'`

Thanks to [mmbb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1395149/mmbb) https://stackoverflow.com/a/41769664/4134285